# DELL DRAC & Ubuntu VPN Connection

Tags: dell, pptp, drac

I am trying to connect to a DELL DRAC card without success by Ubuntu VPN Connection Manager. I have these data:

```
Protocol: PPTP
SERVER IP PPTP: 1233.123.123.123
DRAC IP: 192.168.10.25
Subnet: 255.255.0.0
User: myuser
Pass: mypass
```

where have I to write these parameters?

I have configured the PPTP connection using the graphical tool in Ubuntu 11.10

[image]

... but in the /var/log/syslog I get these messages:

```
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> Starting VPN service 'pptp'...
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' started (org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pptp), PID 18180
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' appeared; activating connections
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 3
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN connection 'Connessione VPN 1' (Connect) reply received.
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet pppd[18182]: Plugin /usr/lib/pppd/2.4.5/nm-pptp-pppd-plugin.so loaded.
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet pppd[18182]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet pppd[18182]: Using interface ppp0
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet pppd[18182]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet NetworkManager[1035]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Apr 15 11:33:15 shinet pptp[18185]: nm-pptp-service-18180 log[main:pptp.c:314]: The synchronous pptp option is NOT activated
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet pppd[18182]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet pppd[18182]: Connection terminated.
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet avahi-daemon[1081]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet NetworkManager[1035]:    SCPlugin-Ifupdown: devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/ppp0, iface: ppp0)
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet pppd[18182]: Modem hangup
Apr 15 11:33:46 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 15 11:33:51 shinet pppd[18182]: Exit.
Apr 15 11:33:51 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <warn> VPN plugin failed: 1
Apr 15 11:33:51 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN plugin state changed: 6
Apr 15 11:33:51 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN plugin state change reason: 0
Apr 15 11:33:51 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <warn> error disconnecting VPN: Could not process the request because no VPN connection was active.
Apr 15 11:33:51 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> Policy set 'Wired connection 1' (eth0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS.
Apr 15 11:33:57 shinet NetworkManager[1035]: <info> VPN service 'pptp' disappeared
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the Dell Drac support PPTP connections?

Comment: yes @arjarj Drac support the pptp connection

Comment: Where did you see that DRAC supports PPTP? Can't find a reference to it anywhere other than this question!

Answer (score 0):

Why not open a browser window and browse to https://192.168.10.25

This should open a window that gives you remote KVM and power/health and options for virtual media. I suspect you may not have much joy with virtual media as these only seem to work with certain versions of IE.

That is the easiest way to connect to a DRAC. There are other methods for SSH/telnet, etc, please see this link if you require more info. http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/smdrac3/drac5/OM53/en/ug/racugc3.htm